# How to override ShortcutsEnabled for textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How should I override `ShortcutsEnabled` property of textbox to accept some of shortcuts and reject others?

clearify: I tried to create a component base on `textbox` and also changed its `context menu` to a more beautiful one. in order to show my `context menu` I tested 2 methods first using `contextMenu/contextMenuStrip` property, but it has a problem (if user presses the right mouse button and move out and leave button, this method won't work) other way was using `ShortcutsEnabled` property that works great. but I like to shortcuts like ctrl+C ,... remain active. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) says that it is possible to override this property to specify shortcuts, but I can not find any example about how it can be done.

---

Edit: I did not find good way to do this. but for solving my problem (disable context menu while shortcuts are enable) I find a solution base on links that @AliTheOne and @x5657 provided. you can catch `0x007B message` in `WndProc` , the good thing is you can still catch `right mouse button click` in `mouse down event` and use it for showing custom context menu and normal context menu will not show. Note that this would enable all normal shortcuts.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg != 0x007B)
                {
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                }
            }
```

and

```
void textBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                //show custom context menu

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [code for textbox](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase@cs/2/TextBoxBase@cs) I think you need to override ProcessCmdKey.

The base ShortcutsEnabled setter sets which shortcuts are enabled in a shortcutsToDisable field, but unfortunately that's private, so you'd have to "roll you own" implementation.

ProcessCmdKey would look something like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) { 
    if (this.ShortcutsEnabled == false) {
        foreach (int shortcutValue in shortcutsToDisable) {
            if ((int)keyData == shortcutValue ||
                (int)keyData == (shortcutValue | (int)Keys.Shift)) { 
                return true;
            } 
        } 
    }
    // 
    // There are a few keys that change the alignment of the text, but that
    // are not ignored by the native control when the ReadOnly property is set.
    // We need to workaround that.
    if (textBoxFlags[readOnly]) { 
        int k = (int)keyData;
        if (k == (int)Shortcut.CtrlL        // align left 
            || k == (int)Shortcut.CtrlR     // align right 
            || k == (int)Shortcut.CtrlE     // align centre
            || k == (int)Shortcut.CtrlJ) {  // align justified 
            return true;
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: good answer but it throw `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception at `return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);`

Answer (score 0):

Base on this: [TextBoxBase.cs](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase@cs/2/TextBoxBase@cs)

You can do this: we want to set alignment by Ctrl+R and Ctrl+L

If you want to disable any built-in shortcuts Like Ctrl+Z and assign new method to it just delete it from `public override bool ShortcutsEnabled {}` and put it in `protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(..)` and `switch..case`

```
     public class MyTextBox : TextBox
     {

    private static readonly int _readOnly = BitVector32.CreateMask();
    private static readonly int _shortcutsEnabled = BitVector32.CreateMask(_readOnly);
    private static int[] _shortcutsToDisable;

    private BitVector32 _textBoxFlags;

    public override bool ShortcutsEnabled
    {
        get { return _textBoxFlags[_shortcutsEnabled]; }
        set
        {
            if (_shortcutsToDisable == null)
            {
                _shortcutsToDisable = new int[]
                {
                    (int) Shortcut.CtrlZ,(int) Shortcut.CtrlC, (int) Shortcut.CtrlX,
                    (int) Shortcut.CtrlV, (int) Shortcut.CtrlA, (int) Shortcut.CtrlL, (int) Shortcut.CtrlR,
                    (int) Shortcut.CtrlE, (int) Shortcut.CtrlY, (int) Keys.Control + (int) Keys.Back,
                    (int) Shortcut.CtrlDel, (int) Shortcut.ShiftDel, (int) Shortcut.ShiftIns, (int) Shortcut.CtrlJ
                };
            }
            _textBoxFlags[_shortcutsEnabled] = value;

        }
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (_shortcutsToDisable == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
            var k = (int)keyData;
        switch (k)
        {
            case (int)Shortcut.CtrlL:
                TextAlign=HorizontalAlignment.Left;
               break;
            case (int)Shortcut.CtrlR:
                TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                break;
            default:
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer, but it throw `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception at `return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);`

Comment: @NokhodSiah I edit the code, set `ShortcutsEnabled` to `true`

Comment: then it is normal textbox.

Comment: @ AliTheOne after doing this change, new textbox will act like a normal textbox , or maybe I missed something. thank you for your time and response. I managed to do what I wanted in a different way, see my edit.

Comment: @NokhodSiah Yep, this acts like a normal textbox